# jcifs cannot write new line to text file

Tags: java, android, samba, jcifs

I'm writing a file from android device to windows folder 
 
all contents are intact 
but i'm **not able to write a new line**

```
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null,nam,p);
    file = new SmbFile(url, auth);

    SmbFileOutputStream out = new SmbFileOutputStream(file,true);
```

I have tried :

```
out.write(("next"+ "\n" + text).getBytes());               
out.write(("next"+String.format("%n") + text).getBytes());
out.write(("next"+System.getProperty("line.separator") + text).getBytes());         
out.flush();
out.close();
```

But none seems to work, please help.

Comment: Just guessing here, but did you try `\r\n`? Alternatively, you can wrap the `out` variable with a `PrintWriter` and use its `println()` method

Comment: sure @gnobal! look carefully it does exist soon after _I have tried :_ in the code above

Comment: `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);`
`pw.println();` no text is written at all as its `SmbFileOutputStream` and not a java `OutputStream` i think

Answer (score 1):

this is how I did to write file with new line

```
                Date now = new Date();
                String strDateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
                String txtVal = "INFO\t" + usr + "\t" + sdf.format(now) + "\t" +count +"\t"+"Ver.1";            
                NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("XXXX", "XXXXX", "XXXXXX");
                String path = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
                //SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);

                SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile, true);                

                sfos.write((txtVal+"\r\n").getBytes());               
                sfos.close();
```